# reading multiple image from multiple folders in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a folder(Enroll) which contain 100 or more sub folders and each of them contain one image. I want to read this image and do some processing on this image. I have problem with how to read them from the different folders ?

note *
( the sub folders name is number like : 1, 2,.. " this number arrived from user " )
(the image name is number but different and not sequential like : 433535.bmp , 126554,bmp ,...)

```
foldername=1; // name of the sub folder arrived from user
d4= dir('C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\Log\Log\Enroll\',foldername,'\*.bmp');// here problem when i put foldername variable 
foldername2=d4(1).name;
w=imread(fullfile('C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\Log\Log\Enroll\',foldername,'\*.bmp', foldername2));
```

help me please :(

Answer (score 2):

`foldername` is not a string. therefore, you need to make it a string. I believe that what you want is

```
d4= dir(['C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\Log\Log\Enroll\' num2str(foldername) '\*.bmp']);
```

Note:

1- you need to convert from number to string whatever number you have. If `foldername` is a string, then `num2str` is not needed.

2- You need to concatenate arrays, it doesn't happen automatically. therefore you need to ad the brackets `[]`.